# Why does this Typescript subclass not inherit the interfaces implemented by its superclass?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface, subclass

Consider the following typescript code:

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo?(x : string) : void;
}

class One implements MyInterface {
}

class Two extends One implements MyInterface {
    foo(x : number) : void {
    }
}
```

Compiling this throws an error as expected: Property 'foo' in type 'Two' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MyInterface'.

When I remove the "implements MyInterface" in class Two, the error disappears. I would have expected that class Two inherits from class One the fact that it implements MyInterface, and so should still be compatible with it.

Coming from a Java background, I considered that I misunderstood the type system in TS, in particular whether a subclass instance "is-a" superclass instance. To verify, I added the method with a string parameter in class One, but this throws an error: Property 'foo' in type 'Two' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'One' -- leading me again to the conclusion that TS subclassses have an "is-a" relationship just as in Java. But that means that I still don't understand why class Two doesn't inherit from class One the fact that it implements MyInterface.

What did I get wrong?

Comment: FWIW, this behavior [is documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#cautions). They don't say *why*, but TypeScript and Java are fundamentally different languages. I suspect the fact that TypeScript is structurally typed (rather than nominally typed like Java) played a role in the decision for `implements` just to be a restriction on the `class` definition (not adding anything, just restricting what *you* could add), but I can't find anything *saying* that, so...

Comment: "Why?" questions about languages are typically **very** hard to answer if you aren't the language designer. Sometimes they document reasons for their decisions, and when they do we can cite those, but often it's a matter of "that was the decision they made at the time" and it's hard to say why (without reading their minds :-) ).